# css user-select text copy string with a space as one copy

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

In my ionic app I want to make a unique code copyable

i.e 1234 5678

So on this span I added

```
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
```

and it works fine, but because there is a space in my string it only copies what I press on, but ideally it should auto copy the entire thing.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

**No**
That's how the default behavior of all the browsers is. A double click selects the word (A word is separated by , `\t`, `-` and other special characters ) and triple click the line.